# ui-dialog box closes but html code remains on page, results in box staying up when using the box more than once

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a page with a popup box used to replace `td`s with new `td`s.  The box works fine the first time, but each subsequent time, the box continues to display after hitting submit.  I noticed that the html for the box is added to the page each time it's called, but it doesn't disappear.

Here's what the source looks like before calling the button:

[image: First]

... after calling the button 1 time:

[image: After 1 call]

... and after 3 times:

[image: After 3 calls]

You can see that the ui-dialog div keeps hanging around.

Here's the html.erb file that is controlling the box:

```
<head>
    <script>  
    $(function() {    
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();  
        $( ".btn" ).click(function(){
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog("close"); 
        });
    });  
    </script>
</head>
    <body> <div id="dialog" title="Select Item">
        Position <%= @i %><br /><br />   
       <%= form_tag( {:controller => :foos, :action => :update_bar_position, :position => @i , :id => @foo.id }, :remote => true) do %>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', @i %>
                        <%= submit_tag "Add" ,:id=> "Add", :class => "btn" %>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <% end %>
       </div>  
    </body>
```

Can anyone advise why the html code for this box persists after the first use?  Thanks.

Here's the js.erb code that opens the dialog box:

```
$("div#show_selection_box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'foos/show_selection_box', :locals => { :id => @foo.id, :selection_list => @selection_list }  ))%>");
```

Comment: From the code you posted, `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` is only called once on pageload. How is this code snippet called in your application ?

Comment: I have a button I press that opens the dialog box.

Comment: What is the code of this click handler ? Is the url loaded through an ajax call ?

Comment: It's weird because it's Ruby-on-Rails.  The click calls a controller method that returns javascript data.  I don't really understand the nuts and bolts of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the script as follows:

```
<script>  
$(function() {    
    $("#dialog" ).dialog();  
    $(".btn" ).click(function(){
         $("#dialog" ).dialog('destroy').remove();
    });
});  
</script>
```

destroy will destroy the dialog and remove will remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: After making the suggested change, I get the follolwing error on my JS console:  `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy' `

Comment: the dialog does'nt exists yet, test if `#dialog` has been dialogged first

Comment: @TCHdvlp, Can you please guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Try the edited code first, and if you just want to test without calling the dialog, you can, for instance, check if `$("#dialog").hasClass("ui-dialog")`... For instance

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of jquery-ui dialog is to leave the dialog in the DOM tree, and show/hide it with

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

If you want to destroy the dialog box, you should call :

```
$('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
```

Note that this will only remove the data added by jquery-ui around your `'#dialog'` node.

If you also want to remove the node, you should also call :

```
$('#dialog').remove();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now the page reloads when I submit the button.  I replaced `$( "#dialog" ).dialog("close");` with `$("#dialog").dialog('destroy').remove();
`

Comment: The page will reload. If you want the page reload to not happen, use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @JSWorld, If I place `event.preventDefault();` after `$("#dialog").dialog('destroy').remove();`, the box behaves appropriately but the rails controller method does not get called.

Comment: ideally, in RoR, you should be doing all these JS actions as callback of the method in update_bar_position.js.erb file which will be called after successful completion of the action and the dialog box closes.

Comment: @JSWorld, If I understand, your recommendation is to have the command to close the dialog box in _update_bar_position.js.erb?  I'm afraid I don't know enough about jquery to make that happen.  Guess I've got a project for next weekend.

Comment: HAHA, I got it!  I moved the `$("#dialog").dialog('close').remove();` portion of the code to update_bar_position.js.erb